# Can you populate variables given to a function the same way php exec does?

Tags: php

When using php exec you can pass it with a variable not previously defined like this :

```
exec('whoami', $result, $status);
```

and they will be populated with information afterwards or initialized in this function. Can you do something similar with a function inside a custom class?

I have tried to search for an answer but not sure on what to search for so i'm sorry if this has previously been mentioned here.

Comment: [This is a very bad idea](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/132870/why-is-it-discouraged-to-create-variables-on-the-fly-php-gives-you-a-notice-err).  [Error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) is a good thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You to declare it as a reference:

```
function init(&$x) {
  $x = 0;
}
$a = 42;
init($a);
echo $a; // 0
```

This behavior is described in the PHP manual. It's the second paragraph of function arguments: [Making arguments be passed by reference](http://php.net/functions.arguments#functions.arguments.by-reference)